# Linux: Are sockets always on device 00:08?

Tags: linux, devices, socket

After opening up a socket in a C program, I ran `fstat` on it and printed out the major and minor device numbers.  I got a major number of 0 and a minor number of 8.  Looking at the [Linux kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/devices.html), I see that major device number 0 is reserved for "unnamed devices".

So, is this a guarantee of Linux?  That is, will sockets always be on major device number 0?  If so, is a minor number of 8 a guarantee as well?  Are there macros in a header somewhere that define these values?

Here's my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/sysmacros.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main() {
    int ret = 0, sock;
    struct stat fs;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if ( sock < 0 ) {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }

    if ( fstat(sock, &fs) != 0 ) {
        perror("fstat");
        ret = 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("Socket is on device %u:%u\n", major(fs.st_dev), minor(fs.st_dev));
    }

    close(sock);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I don’t have an answer for the other parts of the question, but minor 8 isn’t guaranteed: I have one system where I get minor 8, another where I get minor 9.

Comment: hm, didn't even know `fstat` on a socket works, cool! Daniel, could you share a minimal account of code so I can reproduce on different platforms?

Comment: @StephenKitt, Daniel, thanks both of you!

Comment: wow, this is convoluted. I really can't find where `static struct vfsmount *sock_mnt __read_mostly;` from linux/net/socket.c anywhere specifically initializes anything that'd be used to populate `st_dev`. But I'm having a hard time believing this is uninitialized memory, considering the low variance of things we see.

Comment: Just to check, I changed the program so that `fs` was "initalized" with random data (i.e., from `/dev/urandom`).  Same output.

Comment: I wonder what happens if you do that with an Unix socket that's bound to a name in the filesystem. But if you just want to tell if the fd is a socket, `S_ISSOCK(st_mode)` might be a better idea.

Comment: I checked in linux mint, and I also get minor 9 like Stephen.
Anyway, I found something in `https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/master/lib/tc.h`
`tc_get_minor(unsigned int handle)`
The handle depends on the object. (`https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/pkt_sched.h#L71`

Comment: @K-att- thanks for the investigation! If you *don’t* code-quote your URLs, they become links and are easier to follow: https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/master/lib/tc.h and https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/pkt_sched.h#L71.

Comment: @StephenKitt Indeed. Thank you.